# What is the best way to remove the outer JSON curley bracket in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this JSON in the following format:

[image: Screenshot of JSON]

I want it like this:

[image: Screenshot of desired output]

What is the best way, in JS, to achieve this?

**Getting JSON INPUT (for copy)**

```
[{}, {
        "unit_number": "111"
    },
    {
        "residents": [{
            "_id": "5dd690a9f3d9b1336a36f47b"
        }]
    },
    {},
    {
        "tags_info": []
    },
    {},
    {
        "status": true
    }
]
```

**Required Outout JSON format (to copy)**

```
[
    {
        "unit_number": "101",
        "residents": [{
            "_id": "5d5e8f503c7e8c6a08a4141a",
            "firstname": "anubhav"
        }],
        "tags_info": [{
            "_id": "59a6c7915415d3c30cadac62",
            "tag_name": "Facebook Tagg"
        }],
        "status": true
    }
]
```

Comment: please update your question and paste in your json code in text form.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Also what is the way you are using now? And why are you looking for a better one?

Comment: The data is coming from the backend & I'm implementing one dynamic table in the frontend & for which the structure is already defined.

Comment: And you should consider change the title because it doesn't reflect question. You need combain value of many object stored in array.

Comment: Where does the additional data in the output come from?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first try to understand why the original backend implementation is written this way first. But to solve your immediate problem you can reduce the array of property values like so:

```
data.reduce((aggregate, value) => Object.assign(aggregate, value), {})
```

However, there is a caveat of doing this which is that any duplicate properties will be overridden by the latter property values. If that's not an issue `Object.assign` is perfect for this.

Comment: Don't forget to pass an initial accumulator value, so that it works on empty arrays and does not mutate `data[0]`.